# Comparing a Date to a value in a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, string, combobox, double

I have a form with three ComboBoxes called Ticker, Year, and Period.  I fill these in to direct my program to which stock I want it to look up.  For this example I type GOOG, 2013, 1.  So that my program looks up the data for Google'd first quarter of 2013.  But I receive this error message when I try and run my code `"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll  Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."`

Here is my code:

```
Dim dtmCurrentDateTime As System.DateTime = Now()
            Dim Current_Quarter As System.Int32 = DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, dtmCurrentDateTime)

            If Current_Quarter = 1 Then
                If ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 4 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 1st Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 3 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 2nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 2 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 3nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 1 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 4nd Quarterly Column")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Date out of range.  Please lookup and enter manually")
                End If
            ElseIf Current_Quarter = 2 Then
                If ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 1 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 1st Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 4 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 2nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 3 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - ) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 3nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 2 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 4nd Quarterly Column")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Date out of range.  Please lookup and enter manually")
                End If
            ElseIf Current_Quarter = 3 Then
                If ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 2 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 1st Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 1 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 2nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 4 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 3nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 3 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 4nd Quarterly Column")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Date out of range.  Please lookup and enter manually")
                End If
            ElseIf Current_Quarter = 4 Then
                If ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 3 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 1st Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 2 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 2nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 1 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 3nd Quarterly Column")
                ElseIf ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 4 And ComboBox_Year.ValueMember = (Now.Year - 1) Then
                    MsgBox("Scrape 4nd Quarterly Column")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Date out of range.  Please lookup and enter manually")
                End If
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSDN said ..

```
Public Property ValueMember As String
```

Since it assigned by

```
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName" '---> example
```

You can't comparing value like  `If ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I don't understand what you mean by `ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName" '---> example`  Anymore details?

Comment: @nordeen1 .. ValueMember properties will return string .. so your comparation such as `If ComboBox_Period.ValueMember = 1` will generate error .. because `1` isn't string .. and `ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName"` is just a sample to assign ValueMember property

Comment: That makes sense.  But I may enter number "1" into ComboBox_Period so how can I verify if there is a "1" in the ComboBox?  I have tried converting the number 1 to a string (example: `Convert.ToString(1)`).  There is no error this way but then my program didn't recognize the match.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: @nordeen1 .. to get the value `1` .. just have to do `If ComboBox1.Text = "1" Then` ..